# Eclipse plug-ins disappeared after update

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Have been updated Eclipse PDT using `Window->Check for Updates` feature.
After restart all trird-party plug-ins seems like switched off.

Starting with `-clean` command line key doesn't helps.

`Eclipse Installation Detals` contains information about all my plug-ins correctly.

---

Error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_05
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2009-11-24 12:52:00.804
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature for project Search.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.team.core.TeamException: Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature for project Search.
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapNewProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapExistingProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.getProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.isMappedToCVS(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.decorate(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2009-11-24 12:52:00.804
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature for project Search.
```

Comment: Which versions of Eclipse are you updating from/to?
Which plugins are now broken? Just Subversive (is it Subversive?), or others too? Because it might be just a buggy plugin, if it is Subversive they advise using Subclipse instead.

Comment: from Eclipse PDT SR-1 downloaded 2 weeks ago to current

Comment: is it the subversion plugin that doesn't work? or are they other plugings?

have you tried looking at Subclipse ?

Comment: Subversive doesn't work. Yes!

Comment: There is another one - QuickRex. But there are no errors in log about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is use [Equinox p2 Installer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Installer)!
There is no other offline ways to install/reinstall plugins or features.

Answer (score 2):

Mar Cel was right:

Here i have write it in my german language wiki.
You need to chown the eclipse-programm-folder to full access permissions for the workspace-owner.
Start eclipse. Stop it, Rechange the owner back to root, and restart eclipse again.. After that, all works well for me (Eclipse 3.7.2)

Wiki
http://wiki.xstable.de/doku.php/entwicklungsumgebung:eclipse:faq?&#keine_plugins_mehr_in_eclipse_nach_update

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with writing permission of the Eclipse executing user. My guess is that the user can write metadata to workspace, therefore Eclipse shows you that the plugins were installed successfully but are obviously not available in the GUI, as none of the features were really installed in Eclipse itself.

Just alter the Eclipse program folders to give full permissions to the user actually executing Eclipse. Eclipse will then recognize that the metadata is wrong, repair them, and let you install the plugins once again. After that, all features will be available.