# All Eclipse Plugins Disabled

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm running Eclipse 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04. I tried to install the EGit plugin for Eclipse, and after Eclipse restarted, I found all of my other plugins had effectively vanished (Subclipse, PyDev, OpenExtern, Colorer, etc). Oddly enough, Eclispe doesn't list anything as disabled, and running Eclipse from the command line doesn't show any errors.

I immediately uninstalled EGit, and tried uninstalling and then reinstalling some of my other plugins, but I can't seem to get anything working. Eclipse's software dialog listed them all as installed, and I can atleast see PyDev listed under the Open Perspective dialog, but when I try and start the PyDev perspective, nothing happens, and no errors are shown. I also tried Eclipse's update wizard, to install all pending updates for components, but that had no noticeable effect.

I'm completely lost, especially since I'm not getting any kind of messaging that would indicate a problem. What's happened here? How do I fix Eclipse's plugins?

EDIT: The issue seems to be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789013/eclipse-plug-ins-disappeared-after-update). I see dozens of errors like

```
Could not instantiate provider org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature for project X
```

in my ~/workspace/.metadata/.log

Unfortunately, the suggested solution of somehow using the Equinox p2 Installer doesn't work for me.

EDIT: I tried deleting my ~/.eclipse folder and reinstalling my plugins, but the problem persists.

EDIT: I again tried deleting my ~/.eclipse folder, my ~/workspace/.metadata folder, removing all Eclipse Ubuntu packages (including config data), and then reinstalling, but plugins still aren't showing up...

EDIT: There may have been some other weird stuff going on. I'm not sure what triggered it, but at some point my entire file system became "readonly", and a lot of processes started to crash when they couldn't modify their db files (e.g. Firefox). After a reboot, everything seemed to resolve itself, and I was able to download and install Eclipse 3.7, which supposedly doesn't suffer from [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=297329).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try going to **Help > About Eclipse**

Click on **Installation Details** and the **Installation History** tab

Select the date before things got screwed up and hit **Revert**

Comment: If you are going through all this trouble, I'd just give up and download a new version of eclipse and all the plugins, you can still retain important settings as documented [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I uninstalled all Eclipse 3.5 related packages I had installed from Ubuntu's repo, and downloaded Eclipse Classic 3.7.

Comment: I have almost the same problem, all my plugins got disabled when I used the "check for updates" feature. This solution worked, but the problem is back once i try to update eclipse again.

Comment: Sometimes plug-ins are incompatible with newer versions of Eclipse.  If you don't have a specific reason you need to update, I'd just stick with your current version.